# Finding the Current I1 using Polar Notation

Tags: current, analysis

For the circuit in Figure Q3. Convert all voltages and currents to the form X sin(t + φ ). You need
only find the stead-state solutions.

[image]

**Solution**

[image]

---

**My Steps**

[image]
...

It seems that I am going along a wring direction...
How to obtain the answer?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from here,
$$I_1 = \frac{1-100j}{10001}\times 5\angle 0$$

Converting this to polar form, the magnitude is given by
$$|I_1| = \frac{\sqrt{10001}}{10001}\times5 = 0.04999750$$ 
the phase angle is given by
$$\angle I_1 = \arctan(-100) = -1.56 \ \mathrm{rad} = -89.4\ \mathrm{degrees}$$

Comment: I was going to write that except: \$I_1\$ =  0.049997500187484 \$\angle\$ -89.427061302316517°  ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'd love to know which shop you order your components with 10e-9 ppm accuracy from. ;o)

Comment: "Ideal Components" ph. 011-86-..  however my angle is closer by almost 179° to the correct answer. (ah, it's fixed now!)